# What is the oldest traditional children's game?

Tags: folklore, games

Many traditional children's games are of fairly recent origin. For example, the game of [conkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conkers) dates back no further than the 19th century, making it no more than about 10 generations old.

The reliability of claims that [hopscotch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch) dates back to the Roman empire has been [questioned](https://rogueclassicism.com/2009/02/14/hopscotch-origins/), and claims that the [skipping rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skipping_rope) was used in ancient Phoenicia, Egypt or China may be similarly fanciful.

What is the oldest traditional children's game? By that I mean, what game played by children today, passed down by oral tradition, verifiably dates back furthest?

Comment: Ring-a-ring-a-roses verifiably goes back to the 17th century.

Comment: I'm gonna say a Pick Up Sticks like game, or a game which uses stones by throwing them.

Answer (score 8):

[image][image]

***I'M GONNA SAY SENET***

> The games that kids played included a game like checkers as well as Senet and their game pieces were made of small stones and knucklebones (which were really sheep ankle bones). They played a game something like ‘jacks’ and dice with these various game pieces. Kids also had toys to play with including clay rattles that were shaped like animals or people. The wealthy families had toys for their kids made out of wood. These included wooden toys that had moving parts. One might be a hippopotamus that had jaws that would close and open. The higher end dolls were made up of cloth and they were stuffed using papyrus reeds.
>   <sub>[Ancient Egyptian Games](http://www.historyforkids.net/ancient-egyptian-games.html)</sub>

Comment: [References to the game have been found as far back as 3100 years Before the Current Era (B.C.E.) -- and the game was still played as late as A.D. 400 -- so it has been known for literally thousands of years.](http://www.ccgs.com/games/senet.htm)

Comment: Can't honestly say Senet has been 'passed down by oral tradition': but draughts/checkers has a good claim.

Comment: Its from "History for Kids" under ancient Egyptian games, on their website.

Comment: There is a copy of this game at the British Museum in London with a sign that states it was first played 5500-3100 B.C., which was the Predynastic period (before the age of the pharaohs