# Is there a myth that explains Senet's origins?

Tags: egyptian, origins, games

[Fey Ray's answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/1748/4105) to the question [What is the oldest traditional children's game?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/1748/4105) is *Senet*, a game like checkers.

Does the game appear in Egyptian mythology? Is there a myth that explains where and how it came from?

Answer (score 2):

The site [Egyptian Myths](http://www.egyptianmyths.net/) has an [article on Senet](http://www.egyptianmyths.net/senet.htm) that proposes a link between the game and the afterlife:

> **Meaning:** The senet game was connected to the afterlife. Senet boards were often placed in tombs (Tutankhamen was entombed with four, it is assumed that the game was a favorite of his). The game was supposed to be a pasttime for the deceased. However, symbolically the game also was connected with the attainment of the afterlife by the dead. In many tomb paintings and Book of the Dead illustrations, the deceased is shown playing the game with no visible opponent. It may be that in these cases, the person is playing against the powers of the beyond. Winning against these opponents may lead to good fortune in the afterlife.

Unfortunately the article does not cite its sources.